# Where are the other results

Tags: scala

I have following applicative definition and implementation:

```
import simulacrum._

@typeclass trait Applicative[F[_]] {

  def pure[A](a: A): F[A]

  def apply[A, B](fa: F[A])(ff: F[A => B]): F[B]

  def map[A,B](fa: F[A])(f: A => B): F[B] =
    apply(fa)(pure(f))

}

object Applicative {

  implicit val optionApplicative: Applicative[Option] = new Applicative[Option] {
    def pure[A](a: A): Option[A] = Some(a)

    def apply[A, B](fa: Option[A])(ff: Option[A => B]): Option[B] = (fa, ff) match {
      case (None, _) => None
      case (Some(_), None) => None
      case (Some(a), Some(f)) => Some(f(a))
    }

  }

  implicit val listApplicative: Applicative[List] = new Applicative[List] {
    def pure[A](a: A): List[A] = List(a)

    def apply[A, B](fa: List[A])(ff: List[A => B]): List[B] =
      (fa zip ff).map { case (a, f) => f(a) }

  }

}
```

When I execute map on the list:

```
Applicative[List].map(List(1,2,3))(_ + 1)
```

I've got:

```
res2: List[Int] = List(2)
```

But I do expect `List(2,3,4)`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def apply[A, B](fa: List[A])(ff: List[A => B]): List[B] =
  (fa zip ff).map { case (a, f) => f(a) }
```

This is caused by your `ff` size is **1** by `def pure[A](a: A): List[A] = List(a)`.

So:

```
(fa zip ff).map { case (a, f) => f(a) }
```

=>:

```
List(1, 2, 3) zip List(f).map { case (a, f) => f(a) }
```

=>:

```
List((1, f)).map { case (a, f) => f(a) }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a solution to @chengpohi's answer, I'd like to point out there are two classical way of having an `Applicative` instance for `List`.

The first one is `Zip`, which you have implemented, So that when you have a list of values and a list of functions, it applies, functions to element, one by one (first function applied to first element, and so on). Starting with two lists of size `n` and `m`, the output will be a list of size `min(n, m)`.

The second one is `Cartesian`, which, for a list of elements and a list of functions, applies each function to each element. So if you start  with lists of size `n` and `m`, you'll get a list of size `n × m`.

Here is a simple implementation of it:

```
implicit val cartesian: Applicative[List] = new Applicative[List] {
  def pure[A](a: A): List[A] = List(a)

  def apply[A, B](fa: List[A])(ff: List[A => B]): List[B] = for {
    a <- fa
    f <- ff
  } yield f(a)
}
```

This second one is more standard (it is indeed the one inherited from the `Monad` instance) and is the default in cats and scalaz AFAIK.

What you have to ask yourself is, what do you expect when using your applicative on two lists (of size greater than `1`, to have a better idea). What you say in the question let me think you'd better be off with the second one. Keep in mind that those two are **classical** but not the only possible ones. If you need a custom instance, you may define it (keeping in mind that it should observe the `Applicative` laws).